# Plural of feedback

Tags: grammatical-number, compounds, uncountable-nouns

I'm looking for a way to identify a specific amount of feedback *items* I'm visualizing in a list.

The construction of the sentence needs to be generic, so I can't use something like ***Feedback received 14 times.*** What I'm actually looking for is something in a similar form to **Showing 14 received feedbacks.** The problem here is that *feedback* appears to be an uncountable noun, so it would be incorrect to pluralise it into *feedbacks*. A similar idea would be **Showing 14 feedback points,** but this compound might not be simple or flexible enough.

**Is there a succint way to express *feedback* in plural?**

Comment: Showing 14 feedback reports/items.

Comment: Fourteen pieces of feedback?  Or informally, 'chunks'.

Comment: [MASS NOUN] http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/feedback See the examples listed too.

Answer (score 14):

***Feedback***, as you acknowledge, is not a countable noun. Therefore, to indicate plurality it is necessary to attach it to something that does have a plural form.

- Feedback from 14 sources (or respondents, participants, etc.
- Fourteen feedback messages
- Fourteen instances of feedback

I do see some indications online (blogposts and the like) that ***feedback*** may be considered by some to be a countable noun now and that a plural form, ***feedbacks***, may be used. However, it seems awkward to my eye and ear--no doubt due to unfamiliarity.

Comment: I think the term originally given -- _feedback items_ -- is the appropriate venereal term.

Comment: You do not seem to have consulted a dictionary to resolve the "unfamiliarity."

Comment: I've never seen a noun move from being 'not a countable noun' to 'may be considered by some to be a countable noun' so quickly. How does a self-contradictory answer get even a single upvote? [This answer](http://www.englishforums.com/English/PluralForFeedback/vlrx/post.htm) at english forums seems more accurate if equally unattested. Wiktionary says that the French, having borrowed the word, use the plural count noun.

Comment: @ Edwin Ashworth. I did come across the answer you cite at english forums, and, although it reports on some apparent usage of feedbacks, I did not find it persuasive. Nevertheless, I should have cited it under the guise of "showing my work" (such as it was). Is my answer self-contradictory? Yes. Isn't language?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth -- This feedback is a bit late, but feedbacks is widely used in the technical literature when multiple feedback mechanisms are present at once. For example, see http://www.nature.com/nature/journal/v408/n6809/full/408184a0.html , http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/j.1465-7295.1969.tb01462.x/abstract , http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0167691193900333 .